# State of nested Fragments is lost when re-attached to their fragment container in bottom tab navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-nested-fragment, fragmentmanager

I am working on an app that has the following UI structure:

- One `Activity`, called *FoodActivity*

  - This `Activity` implements [bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html). Hence, can show three categories of food: *fruit*, *meat* and *fish*
  - The `Activity` has a big `Fragment` container, where I attach the `Fragment` for *fruit*, *meat* and *fish* as the user interacts with the bottom tabs.
- Each outer `Fragment` (*fish*, *meat* and fish) presents navigation between `Fragments`: it can show a list of fruits, and the the detail for the selected fruit.

  - Hence, the outer `Fragments` have another `Fragment` container in where I attach `Fragments` for the fruit list or fruit detail.

So, it's one main `Activity`, which has a big `Fragment` container where I swap `Fragments`, which in turn nest other `Fragments`

[image: App UI structure]

To switch from one outer `Fragment` to another using the tabs (ie: switch from *fruit* to *meat*), I perform a Fragment Transaction in the outer `Fragment` container:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_outer, fragment, fragmentTag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

The problem is that **when switching the first-level `Fragments`, the state of their `ChildFragmentManager` is not kept**.

For example, imagine that:
- I start in *FuitFragment*
- The *FruitFragment*, when created, attaches the nested *FruitListFragment*
- The user navigates in the nested `Fragment` container, from *FruitListFragment* to *FruitDetailFragment*
- The user switches to another tab
- The user switches back to the fruit tab
- The child `FragmentManager* of the *FuitFragment* does not automatically put *FruitDetailFragment* in the nested fragment container.

More specifically, when switching back to the outer `Fragment`:

- `onCreate` is called, with `savedInstance` == null
- `onCreateView` is called, with `savedInstance` == null

Hence, as the outer `Fragment` `onCreate` method is called, and I cannot tell whether or not to attach the child `Fragment` (as one usually does with `Activities`).
Moreover if I don't attach it (using an instance variable to check if I'm switching back to it) the child `Fragment` container will be just empty.

**Experiments and notes**

- I have experimented that if I add the outer fragment transaction to the backstack when attaching it, when switching back to it, `onCreate` method is NOT called and the child `FragmentManager` will remember and attach the fragment it had before.
  However, I cannot add it to the backstack as per [Google's specifications on bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#).
- Setting `setRetainInstace` to true does not make any effect.

So, what should I do for properly restoring the state of the child `FragmentManager`?

Am I doing something wrong, or is it that everything around nested Fragments in Android is not well supported (or a bit broken) and I simply should not provide navigation using nested Fragments?

Comment: A simple solution would be to replace `replace()` method call with `add()` `attach()` and `remove()` and `detach` depending on your need. `detach()` method call retains the state of the fragment and only hides from the UI.

Comment: That's right Abbas. I came into that conclusion when reading the code of FragmentPagerAdapter. I have posted the answer with the code that works, but if you want post your answer and I'll mark it as the valid one.

Answer (score 1):

As Abbas pointed out, the problem was that I was using `replace` to switch between fragments.

I have changed to code in the Activity that puts the outer Fragment, and it works:

```
private void showChildFragment(int itemId) {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction  transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    final Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_outer);
    if (currentFragment != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Detaching item #" + currentFragment);
        currentFragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        currentFragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        transaction.detach(currentFragment);
    }

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    final String tag = makeFragmentTag(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragmentForViewId(itemId);
        Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        transaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, tag);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        transaction.attach(fragment);
    }
    fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
    fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);

    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}

private Fragment createFragmentForViewId(int itemId) {
    switch (itemId) {
        case FRAGMENT_ID_LIBRARY:
            return LibraryNavigationFragment.createInstance();
        case FRAGMENT_ID_FEED:
            return WebAppFragment.createInstance("feed");
        case FRAGMENT_ID_SUGGEST:
            return WebAppFragment.createInstance("suggest");
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    }
}
```

This code is almost copy pasted from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` as `ViewPagers` using Fragments work like I wanted to.

Comment: Do u have the complete implementation that you can direct me to? I need to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

With getChildFragmentManager() it won't crash.

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
    final FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_outer, fragment, fragmentTag);
    ft.commit();
}
```